# How to solve ERROR: relocation truncated to fit R_X86_64_PC32 in C

Tags: c

For my algorithm I have to test it with large arrays. So, in my C code I have two global static arrays of length n.

```
#define length 10000000

static long long arr1[length+1];
static long long arr2[length+1];
```

For this length n it works fine. But when I make it 10 times (length 100000000) it shows a particular error many times.

```
 relocation truncated to fit||R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `__imp_Sleep' defined in .idata$5 section in C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libkernel32.a(dqifs01360.o)|
 relocation truncated to fit||R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `__imp_SetUnhandledExceptionFilter' defined in .idata$5 section in C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libkernel32.a(dqifs01346.o)|
...
...
```

Codeblock compilation command

```
gcc.exe -Wall -g -Wall  -c "D:\other\all test\main.c" -o obj\Debug\main.o
gcc.exe  -o "bin\Debug\all test.exe" obj\Debug\main.o
```

I knew that it may causes as the address may be larger to link variables.
So, I tried every one of this at a time in the command but, the error is same.

-mcmodel=medium

-Wl,--image-base -Wl,0x10000000

-fno-unwind-tables -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables

-fPIC

How can I solve this problem???

Comment: Not sure where you put the `-fPIC` but it was supposed to go to the first command (compilation, but it probably doesn't hurt to have it in both). And as you are making an executable, maybe that was supposed to be `-fPIE` instead. I think this relocation trouble is a limitation of the x64 platform but can't find any reasonable writeup to support that. Making a pointer and `malloc`ing the memory would probably work better.

Comment: @dratenik Thanks, I use malloc and now it works fine.